# How to call mitmproxy in python and use upstream proxy with password

Tags: python

I want to implement that the browser proxy to mitmproxy, and then mitmproxy switches the upstream proxy to achieve IP switching of the browser, similar to the following command

```
mitmdump -p 9090 --mode upstream:http://127.0.0.1:10800 --upstream-auth username:password
```

But if I want to implement the above command inside python, I can't pass the `--upstream-auth` parameter in, below is the code I tried:

```
#!/bin/env python
import asyncio
import sys
from mitmproxy import options
from mitmproxy.tools import dump

class RequestLogger:
    def request(self, flow):
        print(flow.request)

async def start_proxy():
    opts = options.Options(listen_host="127.0.0.1", listen_port=9090, mode=['upstream:http://127.0.0.1:10801'])

    master = dump.DumpMaster(
        opts,
        with_termlog=False,
        with_dumper=False,
    )
    master.addons.add(RequestLogger())
    
    await master.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(start_proxy())
```

The above code works, but I can't add the agent which requires username and password, I tried two options

1. When changing `http://127.0.0.1:10801` to `http://username:passwd@127.0.0.1:10801`, an error will be reported that `http://username:passwd@127.0.0.1:10801` cannot be parsed.
2. Add the upstream_auth parameter to options, and the error `KeyError: 'Unknown options: upstream_auth'` will also be reported.

Thank you for your help